# JFROG pipelines Windows static node throws "check_win_containers_enabled : Windows Containers must be enabled" error on adding

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

When adding a windows static node on jfrog pipelines, and running the initialization script on the windows server throws "check_win_containers_enabled : Windows Containers must be enabled" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to require some windows features to be enabled manually, here are the commands to run on powershell:

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
>
> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All

The shell will also ask to restart after running these commands, here is where  i found the answer https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Troubleshooting